# C# - Android Actionbar (Menu Resource)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to create an Actionbar in Xamarin VS2015, I look the code up and it says `MenuInflater.Inflate (Resource.Menu.ActionBarMenu, menu);`
 the problem is, Xamarin didn't import `Resource.Menu` 
Automatically for me.

I'm trying to look for that class, but I can't find it.
Can anyone please write it for me? Or at least tell me if I'm doing something wrong while creating a solution (maybe I missed something, cause the creation looks very different from Eclipse android where it asks you what type of layout do you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Resource.Menu.ActionBarMenu` will get generated by Xamarin when you add the menu xml file to you Android project. Do you have ActionBarMenu file in your menus folder?

For example you can define a menu like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/help"
          android:showAsAction="always"
          android:title="help" />
</menu>
```

and save it to ActionBarMenu.xml in Resources\Menu folder.

Comment: The 'Resource.Menu" shows an error, when I look in the "resource" class, there is no Menu, how am I supposed to import it?

Comment: @AhmadSattout: You need to add menu xml file inside Resources/Menu folder

Comment: Oh, I guess I misread the code, I thought Menu was a class or something. Thanks

Comment: @AhmadSattout: Glad to help